# creating async 'instance method' on ngResource object

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, promise, prototype-programming

My app has an Event concept that has latitude and longitude attributes.  Client-side, I would like to use navigator.geolocation to calculate the current distance to each Event and show it in the view.

Below is what I have so far.  It runs, but it's stuck in an infinite loop (error further below).

```
factory('ys$currentPosition', ['$q', '$window', function($q, $window){
  'use strict';
  return {
    position: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if ($window.navigator.geolocation) {
        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position) {
            deferred.resolve(position);
          },
          function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
          }
        );
      } else {
        deferred.reject('Geolocation not supported.');
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]).

factory('Event', ['$resource', 'ys$currentPosition', function($resource, ys$currentPosition){
  'use strict';
  var Event = $resource($server_hostname + '/api/v4/organizations/' + $org_id + '/events/:id', {}, {});

  Event.prototype.distance = function(){
    var this_event = this;
    return ys$currentPosition.position().then(function(position){
      return getDistanceFromLatLonInMi(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude,
        this_event.latitude,
        this_event.longitude
      )
    });
  }
  return Event;
}]).

View (in HAML):
%ys-index-row-right{"ng-if" => "item.distance()"}
  %i.fa.fa-map-marker
  %span
    {{ item.distance() }} mi
```

Here's that error:

```
angular-0195028….js?body=1:69 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"item.distance()","newVal":{},"oldVal":{}}],[{"msg":"item.distance()","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"item.distance()","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"item.distance()","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"item.distance()","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}]]
```

Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zk5ETxCzvzKYAJOlUPPA?p=preview

Comment: Its constantly changing..

Comment: @DrJones plunker added - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'fixed' this by recognizing that you can't expect the view to unwrap the promise.  So, inside the controller just iterated over $scope.events and called a method that 1) unwrapped the promise 2) set the distance value on the object directly.

Answer (score 0):

So I saw the infinite loop error if I chose "block" when the browser asked for the geolocation.  If I said "Allow" it worked.  Having said that I think the code could be tidied up some and broken down into single units of operation to make tracking down the error more easy and making the app more readable.  Attached is the approach I may have taken: [Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/d2kSDG?p=preview)

**just script.js code here**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E', 'ngResource', 'controllers']);

app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  events = [{title: 'hello world', latitude: '38', longitude: '-77'}];
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/foos').respond(events);
});

app.factory('ys$currentPosition', ['$q', '$window', function($q, $window){
  'use strict';
  return {
    position: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if ($window.navigator.geolocation) {
        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function (position) {
            deferred.resolve(position);
          },
          function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
          }
        );
      } else {
        deferred.reject('Geolocation not supported.');
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
}]).

factory('EventService', function($q, $http, ys$currentPosition) {
  'use strict';

  function fetchEvents() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/foos').then(function(result){
      deferred.resolve(result.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function appendDistanceFromEvents(events) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    ys$currentPosition.position().then(function(position){
      _.forEach(events, function(event) {
        event.distance = determineDistanceFromEvent(event, position);
      });
      deferred.resolve(events);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function determineDistanceFromEvent(event, userPosition) {
    var dist = getDistanceFromLatLonInMi(
        userPosition.coords.latitude,
        userPosition.coords.longitude,
        event.latitude,
        event.longitude
      )
      console.log(dist)
      return dist;
  }

  var deg2rad = function(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180)
  }

  var getDistanceFromLatLonInMi = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
    var a =
      Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
      Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    d = d * 0.621371;
    return d;
  };

  return {
    fetchEvents: fetchEvents,
    appendDistanceFromEvents: appendDistanceFromEvents
  };
});

angular.module('controllers', []).

controller('EventsController', ['$scope', '$controller', 'EventService', function($scope, $controller, EventService){
  EventService.fetchEvents().then(function(events){
    // real app is doing other stuff in here
    // so would like to keep promise/then pattern
    EventService.appendDistanceFromEvents(events).then(function(results) {
      $scope.events = results;
    });
  });
}]);
```